# wp_get_archive for category returning different URLs on different but similar sites

Tags: php, categories, array, wp-get-archives

I have this code on two different sites in the sidebar:

```
<ul class="news">
    <?php wp_get_archives('cat=2&show_post_count=true'); ?>
</ul>
```

and this code in the main content area:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2 class="tight"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p class="posted-date"><em>Posted on <?php the_time('l F j, Y'); ?></em></p>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php if(($wp_query->current_post + 1) != $wp_query->post_count): // SHOW GREY BAR ONLY IF NOT ON LAST POST ?>
            <div class="sep-bold"><!-- &nbsp; --></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>This site is so new that there is no archive yet!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

On both sites, the main content area works great, but the monthly links in the sidebar return differently. On one site (WP 3.4), each month's link has `?cat=2` at the end, while the other site (WP 3.6.1) does not. The result of this is that if I click on a month in the sidebar on the older site, it works great, but it fails on the newer site and brings up my home page but with the address for the month. And if I go add `?cat=2` to the end of the link in the address bar, it works great.

As you might guess, I am using a lot of code from the old site (developed for me by someone else) in the new site that I am developing for someone else. I have similar `category-news.php` file in both site's themes. What could be causing the different outcome?

Comment: Is it your permalink settings?  [Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: @brasofilo - Thanks for the edit. I'll try to remember those for next time.

Comment: @josh - I didn't have an archive.php file and after researching that some and creating one I have it resolved.  I don't have one on the old site, though, and that works.  Both sites have the same permalinks settings.